# UISearchDisplayController cancel button not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm getting some weird behaviour when using a `UISearchDisplayController` in iOS 7 (FYI: I happen to be developing on iOS 7 but I haven't tested it on any other version).

Setup:

1. `UIViewController` (linked to a `UINavigationController`), which has:

   1. 1 `UINavigationItem` from the parent `UINavigationController` with a `UIBarButtonItem` search button on the right hooked up to a `showSearchbar` method
   2. An additional `UINavigationItem` right below that which holds a `UISegmentedControl`
   3. 1 `UITableView` with a `UISearchDisplayController` dragged and dropped onto its header
   4. In `ViewDidLoad`, I've added `self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 44);`
2. `-(IBAction)showSearchbar{ [self.searchDisplayController setActive:YES animated:YES]; }`

With all of the above, as soon as I load the view, the `UISearchBar` is hidden behind my `UINavigationItem`+`UISegmentedControl` (1.2 above) - This is as expected and intended.

However, I'm seeing 2 different behaviours:

1. If I drag the `UITableView` down until the `UISearchBar` is displayed, and I either click the `UITextField` in the `UISearchBar` or click the search button (in 1.1 above), the `UISearchDisplayController` gets displayed. As this happens, both my `UINavigationItem`s gets shifted up off the screen, the `UITextField` gets shortened, and a Cancel text button appears. When I click the Cancel button, the `UISearchDisplayController` gets deactivated - This is expected.
2. However, if I *don't* drag the `UITableView` to reveal the `UISearchBar` before clicking the search button to display the `UISearchDisplayController`, when I click the Cancel button, it doesn't work. Instead, it's as if the `UITextField` gets touched.

I've tried changing my `showSearchbar` method to `[self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];`, but this doesn't change anything.

In the 2nd behaviour, when the `UISearchDisplayController` is active, it appears as if the Cancel button doesn't even exist (like in the state of the `UISearchBar` when it's still on the `UITableView`).

Any ideas on how to make the Cancel button work?

Comment: I have the same behaviour. It's really strange. If you figure it out, please write your workaround. I will do the same if I find something.

Comment: For now, my only workaround is to scroll the UITableView to top, and then show the search, like this:
[self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO];
[self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];

Comment: Confirmed the workaround works. I used `tv.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -64)`, because my TableView flowed under the navbar and that seemed necessary.